# What's the best term for a top-level field on the Query type?

Tags: graphql

```
type Query {
  foo: String
}
```

What is `foo`? The spec doesn't give an official term. Some options include "query", "method", "endpoint" or "resource" from REST, and "action".

Answer (score 3):

I call it a "query root field" and I likewise call `Query` the "query root type".

I don't recommend calling it a method, endpoint, resource, or action, because those are those conflate it with concepts from REST that are actually pretty different. Your whole GraphQL endpoint is the resource, effectively.

Comment: i agree, also to generalize you could say "operation root field" which would include mutations and subscriptions.

Comment: @Loren Yeah, that's probably fine too, although to me that might be ambiguous with respect to fields farther down the query tree, especially since parameters can make those fields function a lot more like sub-queries than simple selections of naturally nested data. I think "operation root field" makes sense if aggregating across the three schema root fields, as suggested by vbranden.

Comment: Official documentation also calls the fields of the mutation object "root mutation field": http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#the-query-and-mutation-types